# Is it possible to have a distributed transaction between WCF Services connected to a SQL Azure Database?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-sql-database

Starting with .NET Framework 4.6.1 
[it's possible to have distributed transactions in SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview/). Now, I'm trying to build a proof of concept for that using a SOA, so I'm trying to create a TransactionScope and call a couple of WCF Services connected to a single SQL Azure Database, but I'm failing on that.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    DOConfigurationServiceClient proxy = new DOConfigurationServiceClient();
    proxy.CreateAccessByAccount(accessByAccount);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

I'm getting a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException with this message:

```
There is a promotable enlistment for the transaction which has a PromoterType value that is not recognized by System.Transactions. 1c742caf-6680-40ea-9c26-6b6846079764
```

This is the Stack Trace

```
at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.ThrowIfPromoterTypeIsNotMSDTC()
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetTransmitterPropagationToken(Transaction transaction)
   at System.ServiceModel.Transactions.WsatTransactionFormatter.WriteTransaction(Transaction transaction, Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionChannel`1.WriteTransactionToMessage(Message message, TransactionFlowOption txFlowOption)
```

Is it possible to have a distributed transaction between WCF Services connected to a SQL Azure Database?

There is too few or none documentation about it, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no this is not a supported scenario on SQL Azure.

The flowing of transactions in WCF across multiple service calls relies on the use of Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) style transactions. These specifically are not supported in SQL Azure (there is no MSDTC connected to SQL Azure).

The new SQL Azure elastic transactions are managed by SQL itself, and not by an external transaction coordinator.

One potential alternative is to create a service method that performs all the operations you want to encapsulate in a transaction, and initiate (and complete) the transaction within the scope of that service method.